# Jenkins CVS Configuration

Tags: ssh, solaris, jenkins, cvs

I'm running Jenkins from a Tomcat7 installation on a Solaris box and attempting to connect to a CVS repository on a remote machine with SSH.  I'm getting a failure with this stack trace:

```
Building in workspace /home/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/eLandings_XML_Compile
Using locally configured password for connection to :ext:monknomo@mycvsRepo.com:/opt/project/cvsroot
cvs checkout -D 21 May 2013 09:12:45 -0800 -d jenkins_project xml 
ERROR: CVS Command failed: Error executing cvs server on server.\\nSet CVS_SERVER environment variable properly.
java.io.IOException: Error executing cvs server on server.\\nSet CVS_SERVER environment variable properly.
at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.SSHConnection$SshChannelInputStream.checkChannelState(SSHConnection.java:294)
at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.SSHConnection$SshChannelInputStream.available(SSHConnection.java:288)
at     org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.util.LoggedDataInputStream.read(LoggedDataInputStream.java:227)
at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client.handleResponse(Client.java:626)
at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client.processRequests(Client.java:598)

org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.command.checkout.CheckoutCommand.execute(CheckoutCommand.java:348)
at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client.executeCommand(Client.java:710)
at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs$1.invoke(AbstractCvs.java:246)
at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs$1.invoke(AbstractCvs.java:226)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:904)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs.perform(AbstractCvs.java:226)
at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs.checkout(AbstractCvs.java:192)
at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.checkout(CVSSCM.java:323)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1369)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:241)
ERROR: Cvs task failed
```

When I run the command "cvs checkout -D 21 May 2013 09:12:45 -0800 -d jenkins_project xml" from my tomcat user's command line, it works fine (after putting quotes around the date, and entering my password at the prompt, anyhow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happened to me in a CVS relocation. We moved our repository to Amazon and created linux accounts to every developer. The creation was made with a default password and setted to expire in the first login (passwd -e). Developers that didn't change their password received this exact message from Netbeans.